# EXC_BAD_ACCESS for arrays in Xcode function

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, function

I have this function

```
func pickAttraction(attractionType: Array<Attraction>) -> Attraction {
      let randAttr = attractionType[5]
      if favoritesNames.contains(randAttr.attractionName) {
        return pickAttraction(attractionType: attractionType)
      } else {
        return randAttr
      }
    }
```

and my program crashes (sometimes) on the line starting with "if favoritesNames". On the last time it crashed, the array favoritesNames had 1 string inside, and randAttr.attractionName had a different string. I expected it to return randAttr, but it crashed instead. Does anyone have any idea why?

I also tried

```
if favoritesNames.contains(randAttr.attractionName) || favoritesNames[0] == randAttr.attractionName {
```

and I got the same error

I've also tried

```
func pickAttraction(from attractions: [Attraction]) -> Attraction? {
attractions.filter { !favoritesNames.contains($0.attractionName) }
    .randomElement()
```

}

instead of the other function and I still get the same error

Thank you

Comment: The infinity loop is happening here. That's why its showing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed Thanks for responding. What should I do instead? If that statement is true, I want the function to run again with a new value for randAttr.

Comment: Its calling same method with the same value. You need to update the value based on your need.

Comment: @FaysalAhmed the value seems to update since the variable is assigned a random element from the array. See my updated question. I've tried different code without recursion and it still throws the same error

Comment: What is the goal of this function? You need to modify `attractionType` before calling the function again, otherwise, you will get this infinite loop as @FaysalAhmed said. It's not clear what this function is supposed to do.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `let randAttr = attractionType[5]` is accessing an index that doesn't exist. Can you verify that there is available data if you access the array at `[5]`?

Comment: Yes, there is a value at that index

Comment: What is it that you're trying to accomplish? `if favoritesNames.contains(randAttr.attractionName)` will continue to return as long as `randAttr` has a value.

Comment: I included the 5 for debugging purposes. It should be attractionType.randomElement()!. But, my program crashes even if I don't use the recursive code. See the bottom of my question to see the other code I used

Comment: I think `attractionType.randomElement()` is your clue. Here's what Swift docs say about `randomElement()`: `A random element from the collection. If the collection is empty, the method returns nil.` And, since you're force unwrapping it, you're saying that it'll have a value. The crash could be a result because `attractionType` is nil. Safely unwrap to check if it's nil or not.